# Search list, need only leaves

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following code from [Patrick Brockmann's CollapsibleTree Search](http://bl.ocks.org/PBrockmann/0f22818096428b12ea23) which populates a Select2 list with D3 tree nodes.  I want to change this so only the last nodes/leaves are in the list, not parents.  How can I do this?

```
//===============================================
            function select2DataCollectName( d ) {
                if ( d.children )
                    d.children.forEach( select2DataCollectName );
                else if ( d._children )
                    d._children.forEach( select2DataCollectName );
                select2Data.push( d.name );
            }

            //===============================================
            function searchTree( d ) {
                if ( d.children )
                    d.children.forEach( searchTree );
                else if ( d._children )
                    d._children.forEach( searchTree );
                var searchFieldValue = eval( searchField );
                if ( searchFieldValue && searchFieldValue.match( searchText ) ) {
                    // Walk parent chain
                    var ancestors = [];
                    var parent = d;
                    while ( typeof ( parent ) !== "undefined" ) {
                        ancestors.push( parent );
                        //console.log(parent);
                        parent.class = "found";
                        parent = parent.parent;
                    }
                    //console.log(ancestors);
                }
            }
            //===============================================

    $( "#search" ).on( "select2-selecting", function ( e ) {
                clearAll( root );
                expandAll( root );
                update( root );
                searchField = "d.name";
                searchText = e.object.text;
                searchTree( root );
                root.children.forEach( collapseAllNotFound );
                update( root );
            } )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best idea is refactoring all the function...

```
function select2DataCollectName(d) {
  if (d.children)
    d.children.forEach(select2DataCollectName);
  else if (d._children)
    d._children.forEach(select2DataCollectName);
  select2Data.push(d.name);
}
```

... to avoid unnecessary recursion.

However, as a quick answer, you can simply check if there is no `children` property in the object:

```
if(!d.children) select2Data.push(d.name);
```

Here is the forked bl.ocks: http://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/75f9ac822aace4165caeca1708ee510d/2e24099a8f7d6157783f9d2099754d6abc085a93

Comment: Thanks for this.  In your forked example, there is some matching happening.  The problem for me is my tree has multiple parent nodes with the same name (e.g. a unit of study) and I just want to have the leaf nodes (learning events) in the list and avoid the parent nodes and matching.

Comment: That is, your example has the list with more than just the leaf nodes...

Comment: Are you sure? Can you point me one? `if(!d.children)` makes sure that no parent is pushed.

Comment: Well, perhaps I'm not quite right, but an example is 'Encoder'...it is finding nodes which contain the word 'encoder'.

Comment: Actually, I just realised that your code is working correctly on my tree.  The problem I am seeing is that there are lots of 'unit' nodes in my tree with the same name that don't yet have final unique children/leaf nodes.  All good.